# Why is my response being serialized without navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Today I ran into a small problem with my code. I have an `HttpGet` method similar to the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> Get()
{
    return db.SomeEntity.ToList();
}
```

where `SomeEntity` could be represented as

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    #region DatabaseColumns
    [Key]
    public int SomeEntityID { get; set; }
    public string SomeEntityName { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<SomeChildEntity> SomeChildEntity { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

I noticed that `return db.SomeEntity.ToList();` only returned the top level members of the object (not the navigation properties).

This made sense to me considering I was not calling `Include`. Out of curiosity, I attempted the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> Get()
{
    var enumeratedEntity = db.SomeEntity.ToList();
    return enumeratedEntity;
}
```

To my surprise, it returned the entire entity along with its navigation properties.

I also noticed that an `HttpGet` along these lines also returned the entire object

```
[HttpGet]
public SomeEntity Get(int id)
{
    return db.SomeEntity.Find(id);
}
```

Can someone please explain, *or point me to resources that will explain*, why these methods return the entire object without using the `Includes` method while the first one doesn't?

Comment: Does the first one *have* child entities?  If it doesn't have any, the property will be omitted.

Comment: Yes, in both cases they have children entities. That's good to know though thank you!

Comment: Do you have Lazy Loading disabled?

Comment: You **did not** include the navigation properties, so they are null. Even with lazy loading enabled, I don't think it's a good idea to rely on the serializer to do the fetching of navigation properties for you. You should specifically use .Include() and dispose of the tracking context before serializing the results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on this, so feel free to test and then up or downvote me. When you return an `IEnumerable<SomeEntity>` you don't define a concrete type. You're returning some generic IEnumerable which the HTTP pipeline then strips the virtual properties out of.

When you call `var enumeratedEntity = db.SomeEntity.ToList();` you create a List. That concrete object then gets the virtual properties immediately instantiated. The whole concrete object is then sent down the pipeline including the virtual properties.

You could test this by changing `var enumeratedEntity = db.SomeEntity.ToList();` to `IEnumerable<SomeEntity> enumeratedEntity = db.SomeEntity.ToList();` and `List<SomeEntity> enumeratedEntity = db.SomeEntity.ToList();`. You'd then expect to see the 2 behaviors you currently see based on which generic container you use.

Comment: `var enumeratedEntity = db.SomeEntity.ToList();` is literally the same as `List<SomeEntity> enumeratedEntity = db.SomeEntity.ToList();` to the compiler.

Comment: Not exactly. Var will create a variable which is dependent on the return type of the method in question. You are correct that in this instance .ToList() returns a List<>. But that creation happens behind the scenes and is hidden from the developer. A .ToQueryable() would return an IQueryable() and so var would create that instead. Explicitly defining enumeratedEntity as a List removes any potential ambiguity.

Comment: There is no ambiguity.  `ToList()` always returns a `List<>` it *can't* return anything else. [An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiVuYaC_sHYAhVHw4MKHal0DioQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fcsharp%2Flanguage-reference%2Fkeywords%2Fvar&usg=AOvVaw2sZepS7Q0G5mv_uoHjk5Pk).  So yes they are literally the same thing **to the compiler**.